# Tying multiple dictionary entries to one key

Tags: python, python-requests

I have some code that I am writing, and it is trying to imitate what an API call does.  However there are multiple entries that can be put in the API call that have the same keys.  For example, if you look at my call to the method, there are multiple `names[]` that are passed as part of the API call.

`names[]": ["System/CPU/User/percent", "System/CPU/System/percent"]`

Here is the code that have -

```
def new_relic_api(api_key, query_function, datapoints):
   temp = {}

   if (datapoints != None):
      for k, v in datapoints.iteritems():
          if isinstance(v, list):
              for s in v:
                  print (k)
                  print s
                  temp[k] = s

          else:
              print k
              print v
              temp[k] = v

   r = requests.get(url, headers=headers, data=temp)

d = {"names[]": ["System/CPU/User/percent", "System/CPU/System/percent"], "values[]": "average_value", 'from': '2016-11-30T18:31:00+00:00', 'to': '2016-11-30T19:01:00+00:00', 'summarize': 'true'}
new_relic_api("${api_key}", "/servers/{server_id}/metrics/data.json", d)
```

However, the actual dictionary is only printing out the second `names[]` value inside of the requests call.  How can I fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you write into dictionary `temp` in line `temp[k] = s` different values from `"names[]"` but with the same key:

```
items = {}
k = "names[]"
for s in ["System/CPU/User/percent", "System/CPU/System/percent"]:
    items[k] = s
# items == {"name[]": "System/CPU/System/percent"}
```

It means that last value of `s` rewrites `items[k]` and `items` will always keep only one (last) value of `names[]`.

Another thing is it's better to check if a value equals `None` with `is` operator:

```
if value is None: pass
if value is not None: pass
```

To pass both `names[]` values simultaneously you don't need to split its values, use [requests.get](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#passing-parameters-in-urls) and pass `names[]` as a list:

```
temp = {"names[]": ["System/CPU/User/percent", "System/CPU/System/percent"]}
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers, data=temp)
```

It will be requested as smth similar to:

```
url?names[]=System/CPU/User/percent&names[]=System/CPU/System/percent
```